# Como utilizar una funcion personalizada en Twig-symfony

Tags: symfony3, twig, fos-user-bundle

necesito de vuestra incalculable ayuda ya que no encuentro la solucion

Tenemos un proyecto en symfony 3.4 con plantillas en twig y sistema de autenticacion por FOSUserBundle.

Es multidominio y gestiona datos de clientes y proveedores principalmente funciona bien pero ahora tengo un problema que no se bien como resolver al momento del registro de usuario.

Necesito que dependiendo del dominio, pueda mostrar una u otra plantilla twig en el momento del registro.

Busque documentacion y encontre como escribir una extension personalizada en twig
https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/templating/twig_extension.html

Esta es mi funcion y casi como la del ejemplo

```
<?php

// src/AppBundle/Twig/AppExtension.php
namespace AppBundle\Twig;

use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFunction;

class AppExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return [
            new TwigFunction('server', [$this, 'serverName']),
        ];
    }

    public function calculateArea(int $width, int $length)
    {
        return $width * $length;
    }

    public function serverName()
    {
        $serverName = "$_SERVER[SERVER_NAME]";
        return $serverName;
    }
}
```

La puedo usar perfectamente desde cualquier controlador de esta forma:

```
        $hola = new AppExtension();
        $serverName=$hola->serverName();
        print_r("Server name:  ");
        print_r($serverName);
```

La pregunta es, ¿Como puedo utilizar mi funcion en Twig? yo necesito que en base al dominio en el que se conecta, nos muestr un formulario de registro u otro algo asi:

```
{% extends "@FOSUser/layout.html.twig" %}

{% block fos_user_content %}

    {% if serverName == "xxxxx"%}
        {% include "@FOSUser/Registration/register_content_cliente.html.twig" %}
    {% else %}
        {% include "@FOSUser/Registration/register_content_proveedor.html.twig" %}
    {% endif %}
    
{% endblock fos_user_content %}
```

o si existe alguna otra forma de hacer que dependiendo del dominio del que conectan, cargar unos ficheros u otros.

De antemano Gracias

Comment: He intentado invocar la funcion de esta forma pero no funciona:       {{ serverName }}
    {% serverName %}

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado la solucion a traves de usar directamente en la plantilla twig:

```
{{ app.request.uri}}
```

Esto lo he obtenido de la documentacion https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/templating/app_variable.html

Se puede obtener la URL absoluta, utilizando las variables php $_SERVER:

```
    {{ app.request.server.get('REQUEST_SCHEME') ~ '://' ~
    app.request.server.get('SERVER_NAME') ~
    app.request.server.get('PHP_SELF') }}
```

Con esto me permite utilizarlo dentro de un if

```
 {% if app.request.uri == "http://servidorx.com"  %}
 ....
 ....
 ....
{% endif %}
```